# How can I find the smallest value in an array of Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
var a = [{val:10}, {val:21}, {val:1},{val:3}];
```

the result should give me the index of the smallest val property in the array which is `a[2]`

Comment: what if more than one contains the smallest value? what have you tried?

Comment: What have you tried? Even a simple for loop?

Comment: if the same value then just return the first index of the smallest value, i have tried this
 var indexOfMinValue = a.reduce((iMin, x, i, arr) => x < arr[iMin].val ? i : iMin, 0);

Comment: it should be the index of the object with the smallest value in the array

Comment: @Adam What have you tried so far? Hard for us to correct any mistakes in your code if you didn't post any code :/

Answer (score -1):

you can sort your array

```
var myArray= [{val:10}, {val:21}, {val:1},{val:3}];
myArray.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.val - b.val
})

var min = myArray[0],
    max = myArray[myArray.length - 1]
    console.log("Min",min);
    console.log("Max", max)
```

Comment: Why would you bother doing a sort, which is at best O(nlog(n)) when you can just use a single for loop that's O(n)?

Comment: this is very very very inefficient, finding the max from a unordered array is a `O(n)`, and you are sorting it, which is already `O(nlogn)`... probably with reduce you will have more fortune

Comment: This also doesn't preserve the original index of the item in the list, which is what the OP needs as the return value